# Android build fails with Ubuntu but works with MacOS

Tags: android, gradle, github-actions, kapt

I have an app module with some classes that are generated after compilation by Kapt. The classes are added to:

```
build/generated/source/kapt/com/myproject/myapp/
```

When building on my local MacOS and Ubuntu environments, it works just fine and I can access the generated classes correctly.

However, when I try to build the app from a GitHub Actions Ubuntu runner, the build fails with the following error:

```
/home/runner/work/myproject/myapp/gradlew assemblealphaRelease -p . -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.*** -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=/home/runner/work/_temp/keystore.jks -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=*** -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.***' was 1 instead of 0
...
error: cannot find symbol
import com.myproject.myapp.MyGeneratedClass;
                           ^
```

When I switch the runner machine to MacOS, the build finishes correctly. There's nothing about my project that would make it OS specific and I've verified that the environment is the same:

- Gradle version 7.3.3
- Java 11

Is this a known bug in Gradle or Kapt or something else? Is there something that I need to add to my `build.gradle` configuration?

Comment: You should build it on Ubuntu locally to make sure it does build on it before moving to the GHA-hosted Ubuntu runner.

Comment: @Azeem It does build locally on Ubuntu. Is there something particular about GHA machines that needs to be configured?

Comment: Right. The GHA-hosted runners have [preinstalled software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software) that you might want to look at. As your workflow and repo are missing in your question, it's hard to say anything about what might be the issue.